# Excluir colunas que possuem NA

Tags: r

tenho uma linha com 10 colunas. Em algumas destas colunas tem NA. Quero excluir estas colunas e deixar somente as que possuem valores. Sou iniciante no R.

Tipo:

```
Name       Nota1  Nota2 Nota3  Nota4  Nota5
Patricia     9            8      6
```

Quero ficar neste caso somente com as coluna de Name, Nota1, Nota3, Nota.

Agradeço desde já a atenção.

Answer (score 3):

O código seguinte remove todas as colunas com algum `NA` nelas.

```
dados <- dados[!sapply(dados, anyNA)]

head(dados)
# Nome Nota2 Nota8
#1    4     4     1
#2    4     3     1
#3    2     4     1
#4    2     4     4
#5    1     4     2
#6    4     3     2
```

**Código para criar os dados de teste.**

Apesar de na pergunta haver uma coluna de nomes (caracteres) creio que isso não é relevante quanto ao objetivo da questão, remover todas as colunas onde haja pelo menos um `NA`. Portanto estes dados de teste são só numéricos, é mais fácil criá-los com `replicate`.

```
set.seed(1234)
dados <- replicate(10, sample(4, 20, TRUE))
is.na(dados) <- sample(200, 10)
dados <- as.data.frame(dados)
names(dados) <- c("Nome", paste0("Nota", 1:9))
```